# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I get above error here. My code is

```
 $("#customers").append(
                            '<%= select_tag "customer_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, "id", "name"), include_blank: true %>'
                    );
```

In console it point error at this line

```
'<select id="customer_id" name="customer_id"><option v
```

Answer (score 2):

Try add escape_javascript as below this will solve your issue.

```
$("#customers").append("<%= escape_javascript(select_tag('customer_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, :id, :name), include_blank: true)) %>")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotes(" ") instead of single quotes(' '):-

```
$("#customers").append("<%= select_tag 'customer_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, :id, :name), include_blank: true %>")
```

Comment: now I get this error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

"<select id="studiengang_id" name="studiengang_id"><option value="4">Comp